# PNGs imported into sequencer lose quality

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have exported an animation as PNG files and am re importing them into the sequencer.

- When I view the PNGs in another application they look great
  as they did in the render view initially.
- When I import them into the sequencer however they have lost quality and look pixelated. Even in the preview screen in the sequencer they are pixelated.

What am I doing wrong?
Blender 2.93.

These are jpgs (to save space), original is PNG.
[image: In Sequencer]

[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: Are you referring to the blocky bottom part of cat's head? Seems more like in render - fluid sim border ... If you mean edges (like on shirt) it's probably because it is not Zoom 1:1  ... press Numpad 1

Comment: Yes the Shirt. That fixed it!  Why does the pixellation change at different zoom levels?  what if I want to view it at different levels?  itś final form will be small but what if someone wants to view it larger and how do I get it to not be pixelated when view small (it is very pixelated when zoomed way out...)  crap, can of worms?

Comment: Probably it is not anti-aliased ? ... I can't say it is not happening on my side, and I don't see any option related to it, but I would say if you render sequence from VSE it would be fine.

Comment: Weird.  It looks different depending on what program I open it in.  I think maybe I've just never looked so closely at a digital image before...  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Check your resolution:

[image]

Blender just takes a default resolution here.

To make sure you have the same as in your png you can right click on your strip and choose "set render size"

[image]

Comment: The resolution is the same, and clicking set render size doesnt seem to do anything.  Its weird the files are actually pixelated in the preview window before importing them...  Just checked and ALL Images and video have this problem...

Comment: That’s weird. Can you provide some images with your blend file so I can check it out?

Comment: How can I share my .blend?

Comment: Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.